# How to use Box Muller method to generate chi-square and t- distributed random values?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I need to write an R code in which I will use the Box-Muller method to generate random Chi-Square distributed values. I have a code for generating random values from Uniform to Normal, however, cannot seem to find my way to do it further for Chi-Square and t-distribution.

This is a general code:

```
A <- runif(n, 0, 1)
B <- runif(n, 0, 1)
 
X1 <- sin(2*pi*A)*sqrt(-2*log(B))
X2 <- cos(2*pi*A)*sqrt(-2*log(B))
```

This outputs normally distributed rvs. Now am I supposed to square X1 and X2 and add them up?

And in t-distribution, how am I supposed to derive one normally distributed variable from X1 and X2?

Comment: The Chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom is the distribution of the squares of n independent standard normal random variables.

Comment: Are you *"supposed to sum X1 and X2 and square them up?"* No, you are supposed to square them first and then add them up.

Answer (score 0):

As Stéphane mentioned, you will need to sum the squares of k independent normal RVs in order to generate a chi-squared RV with k degrees of freedom. However, notice that summing the square of your `X1` and `X2` simplifies to `-2*log(B)`. This means that you will need only `k/2` random uniform variables if `k` is even, and `k %/% 2 + 2` random uniform variables if `k` is odd.

A function to generate `n` random chi-squared variates with `df` degrees of freedom using the Box-Muller transformation would look something like this:

```
rchisqBM <- function(n, df) {
  k <- df %/% 2
  
  if (k == df/2) {
    return(-2*colSums(matrix(log(runif(n*k)), nrow = k)))
  } else {
    return(-2*(colSums(matrix(log(runif(n*k)), nrow = k)) + log(runif(n))*sin(2*pi*runif(n))^2))
  }
}
```

For a t-distributed RV with `k` degrees of freedom, multiply a standard normal RV by `sqrt(k/X2)`, where `X2` is a chi-squared RV:

```
rnormBM <- function(n) {
  k <- ceil(n/2)
  theta <- 2*pi*runif(k)
  
  if (k == n/2) {
    return(sqrt(-2*log(runif(k)))*c(cos(theta), sin(theta)))
  } else {
    return(head(sqrt(-2*log(runif(k)))*c(cos(theta), sin(theta)), -1))
  }
}

rtBM <- function(n, df) {
  return(rnormBM(n)*sqrt(df/rchisqBM(n, df)))
}
```